# Error when calling "get" method in JFames

Tags: java, swing, getmethod

I'm making a black-jack type game, and wanted to pass the bet amount from the actualy blackjack frame to another frame that pops up when you win/lose saying the amount won/lost. My code is:

```
public int getBet() {
    return (bet1);
}
public int getMoney() {
    return (money1);
}
```

(all of this code above is in a public class, not the public method).

When I try to use either of these get statements from another frame (pop-up) with the code

```
public class LoseFrame extends JFrame {
    JLabel Lost;
    int bet;
    public LoseFrame(){
        super("LoseFrame");
        JFrame LoseFrame = new JFrame("");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        Lost = new JLabel("Sorry, you busted and lost $" + blackJackFrame.getBet());
        panel.add(Lost);
        LoseFrame.setBounds (300, 300, 400, 70);
        LoseFrame.setContentPane (panel);
        LoseFrame.setVisible (true);
    }  
}
```

It gives me the error:

```
C:\LoseFrame.java:27: error: non-static method getBet() cannot be referenced from a static context
    Lost = new JLabel("Sorry, you busted and lost $" + blackJackFrame.getBet());
```

Thanks to anyone that helped, if any more information is required I can post it, been stuck on this for awhile, is probably a simple error. Thanks
EDIT:
Here's the start of blackjackframe, its over 2500 lines of code, dont know if you want me to post it, but the get methods are within the public class...got rid of some stuff to make it more readable

```
public class blackJackFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JLabel bet,money,card1,card2,card3,card4,card5,handscore;
    JButton hit,deal,stand;
    JRadioButton b10,b50,b100,b250,b500,b1000;
    int bet1=1,money1=1000;     

    boolean gameinprogress = false,playerbust = false,dealerbust = false;
public blackJackFrame() {
```

EDIT #2:
blackjackFrame is being initiated from  a main page through a button. It is being initiated with the code:

```
public class PlayFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
JButton slots,blackJack;
public PlayFrame(){
    super("PlayFrame");
    JFrame PlayFrame = new JFrame("Chrisino Lobby");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    PlayFrame.setBounds (300, 300, 250, 100);

    slots = new JButton("Slots");
    blackJack = new JButton("BlackJack");


    slots.addActionListener(this);
    blackJack.addActionListener(this);


    panel.add(slots);
    panel.add(blackJack);


    PlayFrame.setContentPane(panel);
    PlayFrame.setVisible(true);
}

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    JButton c = (JButton)e.getSource();
    if (c.equals(slots)){
        new SlotsFrame ();
    }
    else if (c.equals(blackJack)){
        new blackJackFrame ();
    }

 }
```

}

Comment: Post the whole code from your first code example.

Comment: What is `blackJackFrame` and how is it being instantiated?

Comment: Use `JDialog` for popups

Answer (score 1):

Your trying to access `getBet()` as if it was a static method using the name of the class 'blackJackFrame'. You need to decide whether your instance of `blackJackFrame` is a singleton. In the case that it is a singleton (you only use it once per execution), you could set your `getBet()` method to be static, and also set your Text component to be static.

However, more correct would be to add a reference to your `blackJackFrame` in the constructor of `LoseFrame`, and use that.

```
public class LoseFrame extends JFrame {
    JLabel Lost;
    int bet;
    public LoseFrame(blackJackFrame bJFrame){
        super("LoseFrame");
        ...
        Lost = new JLabel("Sorry, you busted and lost $" + bJFrame.getBet());
        ...
    }  
}
```

### Where you create LoseFrame:

**if from within blackJackFrame:**

```
LoseFrame loseFrame = new LoseFrame(this);
```

**if from elsewhere where reference to blackJackFrame object is available:**

```
 blackJackFrame framename = ...;
 LoseFrame loseFrame = new LoseFrame(framename);
```

Comment: by create loseframe do you mean initialize it? because im initializing and opening it from blackjack frame.

Comment: Yes I mean calling the constructor with new LostFrame. `new LoseFrame(this);` should work for you then!

Comment: this stopped the errors I was getting, after adding your notes about both public LoseFrame(blackJackFrame bJFrame){ and new LoseFrame(this), but when loseframe should be appearing on the screen, its not not, was I only supposed to add "new LoseFrame(this);" and not " public LoseFrame(blackJackFrame bJFrame){ " as well?

Comment: In `LoseFrame.java` it would be `public LoseFrame(blackJackFrame bJFrame){` and also change the line with `Lost = `. In the other file, use `new LoseFrame(this);` . Are you getting an error? Also, make sure `LoseFrame loseFrame` is the right name your using everywhere. I'm sure you have `.show()` somewhere for your lose dialog.